# How many zeros do we need to add to get a nonzero value?

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers

A student (kid) of mine asked this question to me. I am not sure what to make of it or how do I answer it.

```
How many zeros do I need to add to get a non-zero value?
```

Could someone help? If I were to explain it slightly mathematically, what approach I can take?

Comment: I couldn’t guess exactly what they meant, but try this: hold an empty cup and act like you’re pouring its (empty) contents into an empty bowl. Repeat this several times in front of them, and ask how many times you need to do this before the bowl is no longer empty.

Comment: Thanks, also if I were to explain slightly Mathematically, is there an approach I can take?

Comment: Answering is probably not the point at all. Once you know what they have in mind when using words like "zero" and "adding", you can provide an explanation, but not before that. And then, of course, the explanation will probably be something along the lines of "adding zeros gives zero", like @NickC suggested.

Comment: Have you written `Non-Zero/Non-Zero` on purpose? The title is different. Is division part of the problem here?

Comment: Actually it's Not Zero OR Non-Zero, given just to make it clear. No there is no division involved.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz well to know what they are ACTUALLY asking, I may have to probe little further but seems like an interesting question. I wish there was no to it then simply "it will zero".

Comment: My bad, I've misread it. I'd expect that probing will be most interesting part. If the student actually had in mind something resembling Zeno-like paradoxes (as mentioned by Dave L Renfro in one of the comments below), it would be a nice conversation.

Comment: @AshishShukla You said you weren't sure what to make of your student's question, and assuming they meant "adding zero to zero to zero...", my suggestion was to demonstrate what that would look like and see if that's what they really meant. [People use "add" to mean various things, so it would be helpful to know which meaning they had in the question. Was it 0+0+0+..., or 0000000..., or $0^{0^{0^{\cdots}}}$, etc.]

Comment: In Calculus / Analysis "adding" uncountably many 0s can be nonzero, but adding countably many 0s is 0.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica See this is what I was thinking when I thought about this question. Thanks for the comment. Is there an equation or something proving this?

Comment: I will leave an answer

Comment: @AshishShukla I know a lot of comments and answers are mentioning uncountable sums and such, and that sounds cool and all, but I've never seen anything like a sum of _actual_ zeros with a nonzero value, so I too would appreciate an example! The dartboard probability one seems closest, but can we really model it as an uncountable sum? I've only seen countable sums allowed in (my admittedly non-measure theory based) probability.

Answer (score 2):

✔ **explaining by contrapositive**

Adding up any number of zeros gives zero; so, it is impossible to obtain a nonzero value by adding up just zeros.

**explaining by deriving contradiction**

Let $c$ be a nonzero value.

*Assume* that $n\in\mathbb Z_0^+$ zeros are required to additively obtain $c,$ i.e.,  $\underbrace{0+0+\ldots+0}=c.\\\quad\;n\text{ times}$

Then $n\times 0=c;$ so $c=0.$

Hence, $c$ is both zero and nonzero—which is absurd; our assumption must have been false; i.e., no countable number of zeros can sum to a nonzero value.

---

**Addendum (expansion of my first comment below)**

Consider a target-archery competition in which a contestant has scored $7$ points. Then the probability that they have hit the circular target is $1$ yet, given any point on it, the probability that they have hit that point is exactly $0.$ Here, the sum of *uncountably* many zeros turns out to be nonzero. ([Measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) only need to be countably additive.)

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful...

Comment: @Ashish Shukla: Reply by a smart aleck kid -- What about [Zeno's millet seed paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Paradox_of_the_Grain_of_Millet) (see also [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22does+a+single+grain+of+millet+or+the+ten-thousandth+part+of+a+grain%22)). Or what about the fact each point has zero length, but when you put enough of them together to form a line segment, then their lengths add up to a positive value?

Comment: @Dave Or the fact that although the probability of hitting a dartboard may be nonzero, the probability of hitting its centroid is zero?

Comment: Better is that for each point on the dartboard, the probability of hitting that point is zero. However, the probability of hitting some point on the dartboard is $1$ (assuming the dart always hits the dartboard). Of course, this is essentially the same as points adding up to a positive length (here we have zero-area points adding up to a positive-area value), but for the students one would be telling this to, I think it will seem sufficiently different to also use.

Comment: So, the answer to the student would be that infinity is a deep concept, and that sometimes infinity times 0 is not 0.

Comment: @Sue VanHattum: *sometimes infinity times 0 is not 0* --- This assumes the student knows that repeated addition is multiplication. See, for instance, the sentence beginning with "My impression is that half of US university students" in [this recently posted answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/24383/745). Nonetheless, I suspect any student asking this kind of question is in the other half (even at a much younger age).

Comment: I would ask the student to clarify what s/he means instead of asking us.  I wouldn't presume to know what the student is thinking.

Comment: @AshishShukla I expanded my answer as many commenters are thinking of the uncountably-infinite case.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you want to know that $\underbrace{0+\cdots+ 0}_{N} = 0$. We know that $0+0=0$ and also have that $\underbrace{0+\cdots+ 0}_{n+1} = (\underbrace{0+\cdots+ 0}_{n}) +0$ by associativity. Then proceed by mathematical induction, reducing $(\underbrace{0+\cdots+ 0}_{n}) +0$ to $0+0=0$.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what age the student is or what their mathematical background is. Your question is also phrased as a mathematics question, not an education question. Both of these things make your question, in its present form, not very well suited to this site.

If the student is in high school and hasn't had calculus, then a reasonable thing to do here would be to explain that there are various number systems that extend the reals to include infinite quantities. Examples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number

The student's question can only be answered in such an extended number system, not in the real number system, since the reals don't include infinity. The student's question is equivalent to asking 1/0, and actually none of these systems make that a well-defined thing. But, e.g., the hyperreals do allow you to divide 1 by an infinitely small number and get an infinite result.

If the student has had calculus, then you can tell them that they're basically reinventing indeterminate forms.

Comment: Hi, Are you a Teacher? See neither age nor prior Mathematical knowledge should be required for a kid to understand Zero, and BELIEVE ME IT ISN'T. I explain them Zero and then I ask, if 1 is One of SOMETHING, THEN ZERO IS NOTHING OF ____________. and invariably kids say EVERYTHING. It's not important that they know "The Definition", the important point is THAT THEY SAW ZERO. THEY COMPLETED MY SENTENCE!!! So "question must satisfy certain parameters", "they should know this" is a perfect example of "By the Book" teaching. A kid was trying to know Zero, I couldn't answer, hence asked?

Comment: *If the student has had calculus, then you can tell them that they're basically reinventing indeterminate forms.* --- To me indeterminate forms are formulations of rates of growth, not some kind of generalized number, although I suppose one could classify things like [Hausdorff gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_gap) as a type of number. Also, calculus is not needed to understand indeterminate forms (only precalculus limit ideas at a non-rigorous level), although students almost never work with them, or even see them, until calculus.